# Angular 4 CLI ng build no converting scss to css

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-cli

When I run `ng build`, the generated dist folder doesn't convert `scss` files to `css`.

I have a main.scss in my assets folder and .angular-cli.json has:

```
"styles": [
        "assets/scss/main.scss"
 ],
```

.....

```
"styleExt": "scss",
```

Comment: If this is still an issue, please create a git repo with your app for us to test and update your question. tnx

Answer (score 3):

You can do `ng new myApp --style=scss`

Then Angular CLI will create any new component with scss for you...

You also need to use `node-sass`, install it like this:

`npm install node-sass --save-dev`

You also need to change `styleExt` in angular-cli.json to `sass`...

and use `sassCompiler` in `angular-cli-build.js` like this:

```
sassCompiler: {
    includePaths: [
      'src/app/scss' //here add scss
    ]
 }
```

and you should be good to go!

for more info visit [here](https://www.codementor.io/stevebelovarich/compiling-sass-postcss-with-angular-cli-du107x931).

Comment: I did this before and nothings happens.

Comment: did you do npm install node-sass --save-dev ?

Comment: Yes but still the same

Comment: Did you change `styleExt`  angular-cli.json ? You need to change `styleExt`  in  angular-cli.json to `sass`, also needs  sassCompiler: {
    includePaths: [
      'src/app/style' // here for  sass reference files
    ]... I add them to the answer

Comment: StyleExt is equal to sass and still not working. Angular-cli-build.js doesn't appear in my cli version.

Comment: Did you look at the `link` at the end my answer??it shows the steps in more details, check the page please...

Comment: Yes, but remenber i don't have build.js. I tried to create a new project with  ng new myApp --style=scss and I had the same results, nothing.

Comment: Did you follow the link I put in the answer, it shows the steps: https://www.codementor.io/stevebelovarich/compiling-sass-postcss-with-angular-cli-du107x931

Comment: Yes i did. But as i said i don't have this build.js cause my version is a new one and this configuration is and old way.

Comment: I realize that ng build doesn't build scss to css, but ng build --prod yes.

Comment: Yes mate, if you building for prod, shouldnt miss prod flag... do you need any further help mate?

Answer (score 1):

The content of the assets folder isn't changed by angular. Move it to the /app folder and change .angular-cli.json to.

```
"styles": [
   "main.scss"
 ],
```

Comment: I moved the scss container folder from src/assets to src/, and the I changed the styles path but when I build doesn't appear any css file in the dist folder.